# Symfony Console - Create File?

Tags: php, symfony

very new to Symfony and using the command line interface:

```
Usage:
 command [options] [arguments]

Options:
 --help (-h)           Display this help message
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message
etc...
```

I wanted to know if there was any way to create files straight from this interface? So something akin to `"echo 'This Worked' > test.php"` within the Symfony console, allowing me to push out code tests to new, or existing, files on my server.

I can already write to SQL using `doctrine:query:sql` and wondered if there was something for writing local files?

Comment: I don't think there is a way for creating/editing php files from within Symfony app console (except executing directly php commands), but I would like to know why not to use simply an IDE. most IDEs can connect to Symfony console alongside other important things like using Git, Xdebug...If you still need doing it from command line, then OS built in tools like 'nano, vim' can do it. these are just humble opinions and I am still waiting for community feedback

Answer (score 1):

You may simply create a console command that do it :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

Comment: I am really interested to see an implementation of this. I give it a thought and it seems not the good solution for (How does one can create and edit a php file using `Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument`?)

Comment: The idea of a command line to modify a file in production is not a good idea for security reson. But it's doable.

Comment: Yeh I totally agree regarding production. but even in dev, it is not practical to invent a way of editing php files using symfony application console. IMHO, doing something like `php bin/console create:code --filename=test.php "echo 'This Worked'"` has no sense.

Comment: I agree it's sound unconventional and dangerous. But sometimes it can be convenient to have somethings that do it. See the console can create controller and ask you which method you want on it. So I'm sure that it can be useful somewhere.

Comment: for controller i totally agree with you and perhaps it is the only case taken by symfony into account. Thanks